# Vue router 4 not changing link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework

I've a recursive component NoteChildren.vue which creates the links to a nested view.

```html
<template>
<li>
  <router-link :to="{name: 'note', params: {identifier: props.identifier}}">
    {{ props.name }}
  </router-link>
  <ul>
     <NoteChildren v-for="note in children" :key="note.id" :name="note.name" :identifier="note.identifier"/>
  </ul>
</li>
</template>
```

Next to this list is the `<router-view>`. The page in it has this route:

```js
{ 
// The parent
  path: "notes/permanent/",
  name: "notes",
  component: () => import("@/pages/NoteListPage.vue"),
  children: [
    { // The one the links should change
      path: ":identifier/",
      name: "note",
      component: () => import("@/pages/NotePage.vue"),
      props: true
    },
]}
```

This recursive component creates the links to each children of the upper note and has an unique id in string format. However when clicked the component and url of the page doesn't change. The **link is properly created** tho, if I click on open link in new tab the url is correct and renders the with the correct props. The problem is that doesn't update the rendered component when in the same tab.

The router is on history mode, but hash had the same problem. I've tried to use `force: true` without luck. Also using push and a button instead of a router-link. Looks like vue 3 doesn't react to the new url because it's similar, how can I fix it.

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mcve]. You might want to [import the project](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) into codesandbox or similar, making sure it reproduces the issue.

Comment: Most likely, the problem is `<router-view>` is not `:key`-ed with current url (including identifier), which means Vue doesn't replace it with a new instance of the same component, when param changes. This means certain hooks do not get fired (`onCreated`, `onMounted`, etc...). Given the nature of the bug, it's unlikely anyone could help without repro.